# FreeRTOS in LCP1343

Tags: iar, freertos, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I have been trying to implement FreeRTOS to my LPC1343 microcontroller in IAR. But my program is encountering with this error.

```
Fatal Error[Li004]: file "C:Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\FreeRTOS_Test\Debug\Obj\portasm.o" is not an object or archivefile
```

Can you please help me to remove this error.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupted? You could try deleting it, and recompiling `portasm.c` (or whatever the source file was).

Comment: Yes, I would suggest a clean and full rebuild.